# How to find acronyms containing numbers in a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, find, acronym

I need to make a function that finds uppercase acronyms including some containing numbers, but I can only detect only the ones containing only letters.

An example:

```
s= "the EU needs to contribute part of their GDP to improve the IC3 plan"
```

I tried

```
def acronym(s):
    return re.findall(r"\b[A-Z]{2,}\b", s)
print(acronym(s))
```

but I only get

```
[EU,GDP]
```

What can I add or change to get

```
[EU,GDP,IC3]
```

thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help `\b([A-Z]{2,}\d*)\b` ?

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex won't match numbers (e.g. `123`):

```
import re

s = "the EU needs to contribute part of their GDP to improve the IC3 plan"

def acronym(s):
    return re.findall(r"\b([A-Z]{2,}\d*)\b", s)

print(acronym(s))
```

Prints:

```
['EU', 'GDP', 'IC3']
```

Regex101 link [here](https://regex101.com/r/kmygL4/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import re

def acronym(s):
    return re.findall(r"\b(?:[0-9]+[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)|(?:[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+)\b", s)

print(acronym('3I 33 I3 A GDP W3C'))
```

output:

```
['3I', 'I3', 'GDP', 'W3C']
```

This regex means:

Find any word (between `\b`, which are "word boundaries") which either

- starts with a digit (or more) and then must have at least one capital letter, and then can have other letters and digits
- starts with a capital letter and then has at least another capital letter or digit.

The `?:` permits us to not capture 2 groups (`()|()`), but only one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

It's similar to both Andrej and S. Pellegrino's answers, however it won't capture number only strings like `'123'` and it will capture strings with a digit at any position rather than just at the end.

**Explanation of pattern:**

`\b` - Match a word boundary (the beginning of the string)

`(?=.*[A-Z])` - Assert that what follows is anything followed by an uppercase letter (i.e the string contains at least one uppercase letter). This is called positive look ahead.

`[A-Z\d]{2,}` - Match an uppercase letter or a digit two or more times.

`\b` - Match another word boundary (the end of the string).

```
import re

def acronym(s):
    pattern = r'\b(?=.*[A-Z])[A-Z\d]{2,}\b'
    return re.findall(pattern, s)
```

**Edit:** add explanation of regex pattern.